# Get rid of annoying status-like, permanent bar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

While running a Gradle managed Spring Boot project with `gradle bootRun` command on Windows I noticed an annoying status-like, permanent bar:

[image]

The culprit is the green line. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

The most annoying thing is that it overlaps the server's output on scolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the Gradle log format using `console` command line parameter like below command.

`./gradlew run --console=plain`

Refer [command_line_interface](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#rich_console)